# Angular 2 Reactive Forms Async Custom Validation throws "subscribe not a function"

Tags: angular2-forms

I've already tried every permutation of the answers to [[angular2 async validation this.subscribe exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781775/angular2-async-validation-this-subscribe-exception]) but i'm still getting the exception.

```
import {AsyncValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
export function userNameShouldBeUnique(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (control.value == 'mosh')
                    resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
                else
                    resolve(null);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

and in the component (the last attempt):

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            username: [
                '',
                Validators.compose([Validators.required, forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/)]),
                Validators.composeAsync([userNameShouldBeUnique])
            ],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        });
```

so what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Import Rxjs/rxjs ; This might be the issue

Comment: yeah - that didn't help any - thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
import { AsyncValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function UniqueValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<any> => {
        return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (control.value === 'mosh')
                    resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
                else
                    resolve(null);
            }, 1000);
        });
    };
};
```

Now you have return types well configured. To be added as custom validation:

```
username: ['', Validators.required, UniqueValidator()]
```

Just tested and it works ;)

Comment: what if you want to inject http

Comment: inject http in the validator? what for? @amrabdulaziz

Comment: make server side validation, for example if email already exist

Comment: I'd rather stick the validator with only logic, not with requests to the server. So I'd suggest to have a service for retrieving a list of existing emails and pass them in for the validator as param. Then, it's just a matter of checking in that array. Better than do many requests to the server every time something is typed in.

Comment: what if the array have 10,000 item to check ? it should be checked server side each validation cycle . and if we use service the service should be injected to

Comment: I don't agree with you. If you have 10K, you will have them anyway when requesting the server, right? what does make the difference then? passing it through a variable? it's the same, when you request from server, you are setting the values in a variable, and then doing something with it. If you want a server side validation, do it in the server side, and query it, otherwise, injecting the service in the validator, for me it's a totally wrong approach

Comment: @ Alejandro Lora I agree with you thanks. 
`If you want a server side validation, do it in the server side, and query it, otherwise, injecting the service in the validator, for me it's a totally wrong approach`